# What is the significance of a dead dog in Se7en?

Tags: plot-explanation, se7en

There is a dead dog shown in the climax of Se7en.

[image]

Is there any significance to this image?

Comment: Seems to be a callback to an earlier scene where we see some dogs fighting; https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/seven_unknown.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### None known...

...but there are a couple of possibilities..both involving Mill's dogs.

**The Mills' have dogs in their home...**

Firstly, it's possibly as a reference to another draft of the script in which it wasn't Tracy's head in the box but the head of one of Mill's dogs..

> ...according to Brad Pitt, at one point the studio seriously considered putting the head of Mills’s dog in the box, rather than Mills’s wife.
>
> ...“With Se7en, I said, ‘I will do it on one condition – the head stays in the box. Put in the contract that the head stays in the box.’”, the actor told Entertainment Weekly in 2011.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/film/Seven/alternative-endings/)</sup>

---

Secondly, possibly as a foreshadowing of what is to come.

Mills refers to his dogs as "the kids"...by showing a dead dog it foreshadows the death of Tracey and her *unborn child*.

---

Finally, it's just possibly there for comic effect so that John Doe can say..

> "I didn't do that!"

Comment: There _may_ be a dyslexic/dysphasic meaning too: "dog is dead" vs. "God is dead". That's a stretch, I know, but David Fincher plants subliminal and symbolic things like that throughout his movies.

Answer (score -2):

I have an answer but probably you'd call me crazy for it. It think John put that dead dog in there as a benchmark for the Van driver to stop in there. But he did not kill that dog. Because john doesn't strike me as a liar at all and when he says i didn't do that he's right.
I guess he found a dead dog and just put it in there. I believe john loves animals just as much as he hates humans.

On the other hand; my answer has a gap in it. John did lie once! The moment he misrepresented himself as a member of the press to get information from the police about Miller's house.